# How to recognize a PCI network card (NIC) for Solaris 9?

Tags: solaris, nic

I am trying to install a PCI network card in a SunBlade 150 running Solaris 9. I have tried a number of different cards (D-Link, Netgear, Intel) and none of them "just work". Using `prtdiag` I can see the onboard interface which I do have working:

```
pci     33    +s/system-board  pci108e,1101 (network)        SUNW,pci-eri
              okay        /pci@1f,0/network@c,1
```

However, any PCI NIC that I plug into the motherboar shows up like this:

```
pci     33    +tem-board/PCI1  ethernet
              okay        /pci@1f,0/pci/ethernet
```

The word "ethernet" is a good sign, but there is no PCI ID listed, nor do I have the comforting "(network)" text.

I aleady tried `ifconfig -a plumb` as well as looking through `kstat`. What do I need to do to get one of these cards working? Do I need some special, proprietary Sun card? Appreciate any advice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing the following:

1. Found a network card that was compatible with one of the [Free NIC drivers for Solaris](http://homepage2.nifty.com/mrym3/taiyodo/eng/). In my case, I had an Intel card that was compatible with the "em driver for intel gigabit ethernet controller 8254x".
2. Downloaded the source tarball and following the very explicit directions I found in `README.txt`.
3. Unfortunately my system had no compiler, so I had to install gcc from sunfreeware. As per the gcc instructions, I also installed `libiconv`.
4. Once I had the ability to compile, the `README.txt` told me nearly exactly how to do everything else.